# Convert column to list by using when with 2 dataframe

Tags: pyspark, collect, .when

I have two Dataframe and I want when the column CONCERN of Dataframe2 contains 'all' the anwser in the new column "EFFECTIFITY" (in the same dataframe) is a list off all the serial number "SN" of the column "SN" in the Dataframe1

df1 = Dataframe1
df2 = Dataframe2

all_data = df1.select(collect_list("SN")).show()

df = df.withColumn("EFFECTIVITY", F.when(df2.CONCERN.contains('ALL'), all_data).otherwise(''))

Answer (score 0):

check below scenario. it may solve your problem,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, when

# create list and collect all the SN values from df1 into a list
all_data = df1.select(collect_list("SN")).first()[0]

df2 = df2.withColumn("EFFECTIVITY", when(df2.CONCERN.contains('ALL'), all_data).otherwise([]))
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried but it doesn't work, i'm still looking.